# How to select data and report a multinomial logistic regression for microbiome

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

recently I have been working with gut microbiome data, like abundance and its metabolic content (but for purposes of the question this may be indifferent). I'm inexpert in the field of multinomial logistic regression and also in how to report it in a scientific paper. I'm working in R, with a sample of 402 individuals (213 for healthy or control or reference group, 56 group 1, 50 group unhealthy 2, 44 group unhealthy 3,  39 group unhealthy 4), the scope of my analysis is to identify those bacterial interactions  (3 types of interaction: cooperative, competitive, no interaction) that are related to each group and how much does each bacterial interaction contribute to describing each group.

My issue:
I have an independent categorical variable with 3 categories (3 dummies). Then I generate my model and I found that just 1 of my 3 dummies is significant.
1.- Should I generate a new model removing those dummies that aren't significant?
2.- or should I report every Beta despite they aren't significant?
3.- can you show me some paper as an example?

Comment: Please provide more info about the aims of your analysis - this has a big effect on the answers to your questions. For example, are you building a predictive model, or are you wanting to test a specific hypothesis?

Comment: It also depends on sample size. Maybe only one level is significant, just because you do not have enough data to show differences in the other groups. Furthermore, significance does not say anything about how big the effect is.

Comment: ok, I will add that info. Thanks for the comments!